# Cadstar : Define pad only on bottom or top layer

Tags: pcb-layers

I currently design with cadstar and when I want to check my PCB layout I see my SMD pads defined both on top and bottom layer. I think it is normal because these pads are defined on the both side in the assignment.

Do you know how is possible to define directly on pcb if the pads are on top or bottom side ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found myself the solution, it is obvious when you know... In fact you just need to define the pad on Side "Minimum" this definition put the pad on the first Layer when you route. In my case, the error was a definition in Thought Hole.

I hope that can help someone else.